# Adding labels after meeting a zoom threshold in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, labeling, markers, mapping

I'm making a map in Leaflet and I have up to two labels per marker:

```
var redIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-red.png',
  shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [12, 41],
  popupAnchor: [1, -34],
  shadowSize: [41, 41]
});

var marker1 = L.marker([25.777085, -80.193935], {icon: redIcon}).addTo(mymap);
var marker2 = L.marker([25.759461, -80.204921], {icon: redIcon}).addTo(mymap);

marker1.bindPopup('<div style="line-height: 1.2em;"><table align="center" border="0"  cellpadding=".25" cellspacing=".25" width="95%"><tbody><tr><td colspan="2"><div style="padding: 0.1em; background-color: rgb(0,0,255); text-align: center;"><b style="color:white;">Number 1</b></div></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center;"> <strong>$456K </strong><br><strong>2 </strong>bd |&nbsp;<strong>2 &nbsp;</strong>ba |&nbsp;<strong>1,008 </strong>sqft<br><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/189349/pexels-photo-189349.jpeg" height="50px" width="50px"/></td><td style="text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></div>');
marker1.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            this.openPopup();
        });
        marker1.on('mouseout', function (e) {
            this.closePopup();
        });

function createLabel(layer, text, count){
    //removeLabel(layer);
    var icon = createStaticLabelIcon(text);
  var testspan = document.createElement("span");
  document.body.appendChild(testspan); 

  testspan.className = "textwidth";
  testspan.style.fontSize = "10px";
  testspan.innerHTML = text;
  var width = testspan.clientWidth +11;
  var posY = 0;
  if( count == 1){
     posY = -4;
  } else if( count == 2){
     posY = -24;
  }

  icon.options.iconAnchor = [width  / 2, posY]; //That the label is centered

  var label = L.marker(layer.getLatLng(),{icon: icon}).addTo(mymap);
  layer.appendedLabel = label;

  document.body.removeChild(testspan); 
}

function createStaticLabelIcon(labelText) {
    return L.divIcon({
        className: "leaflet-marker-label",
        html: '<span class="leaflet-marker-iconlabel" style="background: #CB2B3E; color: #FFFFFF;";>'+labelText+'</span>',
        text: labelText,
    });
}

createLabel(marker1, "Label 1.1",1);
createLabel(marker1, "Label 1.2",2);
createLabel(marker2, "Label 2",1);
```

What I'd like to do is hide the labels until the user zooms in past a certain threshold. Does anyone know how to do that? Moreover, if it is possible to only display labels after a certain zoom, is there a way so that some labels are always shown (like Label 1.1 above) whereas others only appear after passing the zoom threshold (like Label 1.2 above)?

I try adding this code, which has worked for another poster, and it didn't work for me (my map is called `mymap`):

```
var show_label_zoom = 20; // zoom level threshold for showing/hiding labels
var labels_visible = true;
function show_hide_labels() {
    var cur_zoom = mymap.getZoom();
    if(labels_visible && cur_zoom < show_label_zoom) {          
        labels_visible = false;
        mymap.eachLayer(layer => layer.hideLabel && layer.hideLabel());               
    }
    else if(!labels_visible && cur_zoom >= show_label_zoom) {           
        labels_visible = true;
        mymap.eachLayer(layer => layer.showLabel && layer.showLabel());               
    }
}
mymap.on('zoomend', show_hide_labels);
show_hide_labels();
```

I've learned the `appendedLabel` portion of my code isn't standard for Leaflet. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419337/how-to-add-text-below-a-marker-in-leaflet?noredirect=1&lq=1) (last post) when trying to trouble shoot an issue of adding multiple labels.

Comment: Please edit your question and add info where does this `.appendedLabel` method comes from. It's not part of standard Leaflet. You are also using Leaflet 0.7.7 which is way obsolete. Any reason for that?

Comment: Done. I'm using Leaflet 0.7.7 because I'm a total newbie and didn't know better. Didn't mean to end up using something obsolete.

Comment: Sorry for my nonsense comment, `.appendedLabel` is custom property, not method, so it's OK. What's not OK are `.showLabel` and `hideLabel` methods which do not exist.

Comment: Got it. I thought they did exist based on the post I linked to above and this thread here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label/issues/83. I'll start looking for a different method. Thanks!

Comment: You could achieve what you want by putting those labels that you want to hide, not directly on map but in a separate group layer. You can then add/remove this group layer to the map depending on zoom.

Comment: I think my only problem with that is that the the function I've used from elsewhere for `createLabel` adds them to the map automatically: `var label = L.marker(layer.getLatLng(),{icon: icon}).addTo(mymap);
  layer.appendedLabel = label;`. When I remove `addTo(mymap)` and instead stick to to the end of `createLabel` (like this: `createLabel(marker1, "Label 1.1",1).addTo(mymap);`) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid dealing with each marker separately, you can put those labels that you want to show only at certain zoom level, not directly on map but in a separate group layer. You can then add/remove this group layer to the map depending on zoom.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var markerGroup = L.layerGroup();

function createLabel(layer, text, count){
  .
  .
  .
  var label = L.marker(layer.getLatLng(),{icon: icon});
  layer.appendedLabel = label;
  if (count == 1)
    label.addTo(mymap);
  else {
    label.addTo(markerGroup);
  }
  .
  .
  .
}

var show_label_zoom = 20;      
var currZoom = mymap.getZoom();

function show_hide_labels() {
  var zoom = mymap.getZoom();
  if (zoom > currZoom) {
    if (zoom == show_label_zoom) markerGroup.addTo(mymap);
    }
  else {
    if (currZoom == show_label_zoom) markerGroup.removeFrom(mymap);
  }
  currZoom = mymap.getZoom();
}

mymap.on('zoomend', show_hide_labels);
if (currZoom >= show_label_zoom) markerGroup.addTo(mymap);
```